# method not overriding from abstract superclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class

my class `KTree` is extending the abstract class `GraphClass` but one of the methods defined in `GraphClass` isn't able to be overriden.

---

```
public abstract class GraphClass<V extends VertexInterface<?> ,E extends EdgeInterFace <V,?>> implements UndirectedGraph<V,E>{
//other methods

    @Override
    public boolean addEdge(E e, V v, V v1) {
        return false;
    }

//more methods
}
```

---

the original method `addEdge(E e, V v, V v1)` is defined in the interface `UndirectedGraph<V,E>`

---

```
public class KTree<V extends VertexInterface<?> ,E extends EdgeInterFace <V,?>> extends GraphClass {
//other methods

    @Override
    public boolean addEdge(E e, V v, V v1) {

        if(!this.Nodes.contains(v) || !this.Nodes.contains(v1) || this.Edges.containsValue(e)){
            return false;
        }

        v.setDegree(v.getDegree()+1);
        v1.setDegree(v1.getDegree()+1);

        this.Edges.put(e.getHashCode(),e);

        return true;
    }

//more methods
}
```

---

in the `KTree` class the `addEdge(E e, V v, V v1)` throws the error

> 'addEdge(E, V, V)' in 'KTree' clashes with 'addEdge(E, V, V)' in
>   'GraphClass';both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides
>   the other

the @override in `KTree` throws the error

> Method does not override from its superclass

---

I understand why they have the same type erasure but I thought that if I added the @override it would default to that version of the method for all `KTree` instances. What I am looking to do is just to override the method from `GraphClass` but don't know why it doesn't recognize the @override. Does this have to do with overriding a method thats already overriding an interface method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because the `E` and `V` defined in `KTree` aren't the same as the ones defined in `GraphClass`. Basically, you're inheriting the raw form of `GraphClass`. Change you declaration of of `KTree` to this:

```
public class KTree<V extends VertexInterface<?>, E extends EdgeInterFace <V, ?>> extends GraphClass<V, E>
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you've used `GraphClass` in its raw form (no type parameters) in the `KTree` declaration.

It should be:

```
public class KTree<V extends VertexInterface<?> ,E extends EdgeInterFace <V,?>> extends GraphClass<V, E>
```